# What is a namespace object?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='sort given numbers')
parser.add_argument('-s', nargs = '+', type = int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

On command line when I run the command

`python3 file_name.py -s 9 8 76`

It prints 
`Namespace(s=[9, 8, 76])`.

How can I access the list [9, 8, 76]?
What is the namespace object. Where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

- The documentation for `argparse.Namespace` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace).
- You can access the `s` attribute by doing `args.s`.
- If you'd like to access this as a dictionary, you can do `vars(args)`, which means you can also do `vars(args)['s']`

Comment: argparse.Namespace can also be used for type-hinting! i.e. args: argparse.Namespace. Your answer helped me figure out that it was a module specific Namespace type instead of global.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [result object that `argparse` returns](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace); the items named are attributes:

```
print(args.s)
```

This is a very simple object, deliberately so. Your parsed arguments are attributes on this object (with the name determined by the long option, or if set, the `dest` argument).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Where can I know more about this namespace object? Where and how is it used? I couldn't find anything good on googling.

Comment: I linked you to the documentation in my answer already. There is not that much to say about it, really.

Answer (score 2):

you can access as `args.s` , "NameSpace class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a readable string representation. If you prefer to have dict-like view of the attributes, you can use the standard Python idiom, vars()." [Source](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace)